# ios tab bar button to modal view

Tags: ios

I'm using idev-recipes/RaisedCenterTabBar and I want a modal view called from the center button, not a camera.

Code is here:
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to raise a modal view from tapping a button on a `UITabBar`. You need to make your question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create your own subclass of UITabBarController and then add in this method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item  {

}
```

You will be able to tell what item was selected and then instantiate a modal VC inside there.

Comment: what about the current VC attached to the item in the tab bar? Is that to be ignored, or can I remove it while keeping the tab bar item?

Comment: I think you can ignore it.  It can't be removed (a TabBarController needs to have a VC for every tab).

Comment: But when I open the modal won't it switch VCs behind it and then when done with modal show blank VC? How do I get it to just ignore it and not render default action?

Comment: @stewart715 use `tabBarController(_:shouldSelectViewController:)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better approach to follow in order to accomplish that. And much easier.

What I understand by implementing using this methodology: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar is that strange things are happening when you are trying to hide the tab bar. So the best solution I found for me (the same thing as you do) is here: http://www.lantean.co/display-a-modal-uiviewcontroller-when-a-uitabbaritem-is-pressed/

There is no need to do anything else. Just ignore the view controller that the UITabBarItem is associated with and present your modal view! That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could just use the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), with the 
 `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` 
 method. 
The method gets sent to the delegate, when somebody presses a button in the tab bar. In there you could check if it was the right button, and then instantiate the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Either with subclassing or by using the delegate, you can simply check if the item selected is your middle button and if it is, have the tab bar select the item that was previously selected and then present your model view controller.  Since you'll be doing this within the same RunLoop source that the original selection happened, the tab selection will effectively be undone without ever switching to the middle VC.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code sample provided by you =>
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

The central raised tab button is a UIButton, so just set the action of that button like this in BaseViewController.m class

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showmodalview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then in showmodalview method write this code=>

```
-(void)showmodalview
{
    UIViewController *view1=[[UIViewController alloc] init]; // you can use any view controller instance you want ,this is just the example.
    [self presentModalViewController:view1 animated:YES];
}
```